# Cannot read property push of undefined in my node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am new to node and express. When I issue the command `npm start` to start my application, I am getting this error `Cannot Read property push of undefined` from my `index.js` file.

This is the code causing issue. Please help me:

```js
proto.route = function route(path) {
    var route = new Route(path);

    var layer = new Layer(path, {
        sensitive: this.caseSensitive,
        strict: this.strict,
        end: true
    }, route.dispatch.bind(route));

    layer.route = route;
    this.stack.push(layer);
    return route;
};
```

These are my imports in the file:

```js
var Route = require('./route')
var Layer = require('./layer');
var methods = require('methods');
var mixin = require('utils-merge');
var debug = require('debug')('express:router');
var deprecate = require('depd')('express');
var flatten = require('array-flatten');
var parseUrl = require('parseurl');
var setPrototypeOf = require('setprototypeof')
```

Please help me in fixing this. I am not getting any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line `this.stack.push(layer);`. The element `stack` is defined elsewhere and in the function he cannot access it.